# What is the most efficient way to sort a list of dates in string format in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have a list of dates in the string format, 'YYYYMMDD.' How do I sort the list in regular and reverse order?

Comment: I almost never ask this, but: what have you tried?  (The simplest things I could imagine trying would work.)

Comment: you already have it in the perfect format for sorting!  list.sort(), or list.sort(reverse=True).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For that particular format, you can just sort them as strings

```
>>> sorted(['20100405','20121209','19990606'])
['19990606', '20100405', '20121209']
>>> sorted(['20100405','20121209','19990606'], reverse=True)
['20121209', '20100405', '19990606']
```

This works because in that format the digits are in the order of most significant to least significant

Answer (score 7):

These are the two ways:

```
print sorted(my_list)
print sorted(my_list, reverse=True)
```

The whole reason people use dates in YYYYMMDD format is so that lexicographic (string) sorting will accomplish a date sort.

Answer (score 3):

Strings sort naturally. Use `list.sort` (in-place) or built-in `sorted` (copying).

Both accept a boolean parameter named `reverse` which defaults to `False`; set to `True` fr reverse order.